# ML.NET and Many to many relation

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I want to use ML.Net Multi-class classification in my current project that collects error logs from one my company systems.

Point is to add tags to errors and one point in the future train a model to predict and assign tags to incoming logs.

I'm using a model builder and I can't see my table relations, I store all logs in one table, tags in another and all relations in the third one.

```
|Logs| <-- |LogId|TagId| --> |Tags|
```

My goal is to classify table with `TagId` column based on `Logs` table - is that possible? or do I have to have everything in one table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, machine learning algorithms are dealing with the fully 'denormalized' and 'prepared' data: every training example is vector of floats ('features'), and one 'ground truth' value.

ML.NET helps with some of the typical pre-processing tasks, like text featurization, one-hot encoding, rescaling/normalization, but it doesn't provide pretty much any 'relational' functionality (no JOINs).

So, you should de-normalize / 'flatten' your data before you pass it to ML.NET.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the answer I was looking for.